# Assign a default app to a file type in Android 11

Tags: files, android-11

Is it possible to assign a default app to a file type in Android 11?

In Android 7 I had no problem to assign e.g., `.mp3` file type to a particular application (e.g. to Laya Music Player).

Now, in Android 11 I don't see any way how to reach it. If it is possible, please tell me, how.

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, I want in *arbitrary* file manager:

1. See the icon of the application chosen by me (e.g. Laya Music Player) near every `.mp3` file.
2. After tap (or double-tap) on to be opened in that application (Laya Music Player).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the fully satisfactory solution, but the [beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams)' comment under the question suggests that *Android most likely doesn't provide this feature anymore.*

Some file managers, as [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/android.htm) or [MiXplorer](https://mixplorer.com) have an option to

- assign different file extensions (as `.mp3` or `.pdf`) to an appropriate, selectable application,
- save those assignments for future use, and
- edit / remove every such individual assignment.

Unfortunately, such assignments are **only internal** ones, i.e.

- those file managers **will** open the appropriate applications by tapping / double-tapping on the file name,
- but other applications (and Adroid OS, too) **will not change** their appearance and behavior.